# Spring Aws Kinesis Messages are not consumed in order

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I am pushing 100 messages on to stream with 1 shrad.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        myOutBound:
          destination: my-stream
          contentType: application/json
```

I am pushing messages in loop for testing purpose

```
@EnableBinding(MyBinder.class)
public class MyProcessor {

  @Autowired
  private MyBinder myBinder;

  public void processRollup() {
    List<MyObject> myObjects =  IntStream.range(1, 100)
        .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
        .map(s-> new MyObject(s))
        .collect(toList());
    myObjects.forEach(messagePayload ->{
      System.out.println(messagePayload.getId());
      myBinder.myOutBound()
          .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(messagePayload)
              .build());
        }
    );
  }

}
```

I am consuming messages like below

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        RollUpInboundStream:
          group: my-consumer-group
          destination: my-stream
          content-type: application/json
```

The message consumption is not ordered.

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to consider. First of all the producer in the Binder is based on the `KinesisMessageHandler` with `async` mode by default:

```
messageHandler.setSync(producerProperties.getExtension().isSync());
```

So, even if it looks for you that you send those messages in the right order one by one, it doesn't mean that they reach a stream on AWS at the same order.

Also there is no guarantee that they are settled on AWS in the same order anyway, even if you send them in a sync mode.

See here: [Amazon Kinesis and guaranteed ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246678/amazon-kinesis-and-guaranteed-ordering)

Also you can achieve an order guarantee within the same shard via an explicit `sequenceNumber`:

> To guarantee strictly increasing ordering, write serially to a shard and use the SequenceNumberForOrdering parameter.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html

Unfortunately the Kinesis Binder doesn't support that option at the moment, but we can overcome it via an explicit `AwsHeaders.SEQUENCE_NUMBER` set into the message before sending it into the `output` destination of the binder:

```
String sequenceNumber = messageHeaders.get(AwsHeaders.SEQUENCE_NUMBER, String.class);
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(sequenceNumber) && this.sequenceNumberExpression != null) {
        sequenceNumber = this.sequenceNumberExpression.getValue(getEvaluationContext(), message, String.class);
    }
```

Comment: can you help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594545/spring-aws-kinesis-binder-provisionedthroughputexceededexception-while-consuming

Comment: Where should I insert the code you mentioned about the Header? How can I set the setSync in a spring boot application?

Comment: You probably need to open a new SO question with much more info. This one is like 4-5 years old already, so something might be off.