# "Amazon Kinesis Data Streams" not completely realtime stream?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

[image: data flow]

I expect Kinesis data stream (and succeeding process such as KDS firehose) to send data sequentially in real time.
However, when I check the data sequence, it does not seem what I expected.

I get audio data by pyaudio, and send data to KDS by while loop. Its sequence is continuous.
However when I check the cloudwatch log of lambda function (that is triggered when one data arrived at KDS), its sequence number is not continuous.

Could someone tell me how it happens and how to make it sequential?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446535/1922235 - Try this one, might help.

Comment: "SequenceNumberForOrdering" solved this problem. Thankyou!